# Generating Transaction Traffic for Testing

Tags: testnets

Is there a command line arg,  tool or script to automatically generate transaction traffic from multiple nodes on a private test network?

Comment: I have a sketch of one here: https://github.com/jorpic/eth-benchmark

Comment: We're working on this for QuickBlocks. Still pre-alpha.